# How can I change the Blending Modes in Adobe Illustrator?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, cs5

I can't seem to find it, even though it's probably looking me dead in the face. I'm new to Illustrator so I'm still trying to figure out the ins and outs of it. I'm using CS5. Any and all help is appreciated!

Answer (score 10):

What [AdamSchuld says below](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/a/19923/3327) is the standard way (transparency window).

A second way of setting blending modes with **finer control on what they apply to** is via the super-useful `Appearance` window.

With this, you can set the blending mode (and opacity) of individual fills and strokes, as well as of certain effects. You can also give elements multiple fills and strokes with different blending modes to each other, which is sometimes useful if you're doing something complicated.

[image]

Comment: +1 actually, I didn't know that you could separate the opacity of the stroke from fill. Is that a recent change in Illustrator?

Comment: I don't think so, I think it was possible at least in CS4, but I think it's one of those lesser-known features. I discovered this by accident quite recently while trying to do something else with the appearance window and now use it quite a lot. There are lots of little non-obvious tricks with using the appearance panel.

Answer (score 4):

You can find the blending modes in the **Transparency Window** accessed by Window → Transparency.
[image: Transparency Window]

Comment: Tank you
It was used a lot by me