# How can i make this opacity effect

Tags: adobe-illustrator, transparency

How can i make this effect using illustrator CC .
I try to make it reducing the opactiy of red rectangle ,but it dosent give a result like this [image]

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/19922/how-can-i-change-the-blending-modes-in-adobe-illustrator

Answer (score 5):

Set Document color to RGB and place the image. Draw the rectangle and fill it. Then on Transparency Panel change Blending mode to Multiply.

Answer (score 3):

Looks like the blending mode of that layer is just set to multiply. Obvious then there's some focus manipulation on the picture underneath too.

[image]

Comment: I simply can't believe you photo-bombed that deer's selfie!

Comment: haha I swear the deer was on board!

Answer (score 0):

Create a colored layer on top of the image requiring the effect.
Change the blending mode on the layer palette
Various blending mode will show different type of effects that would look good.
Also can try different adjustment layers blending modes

Comment: Hello Emily and welcome! Could you please add some more detail to your answer, perhaps including relevant screenshots of the process? It would make your answer more valuable. Thanks for the contribution!